# How can I configure IIS to allow for multithreaded downloads?

Tags: download, iis, iis-7

I'm running IIS 7, and frequently download larger files from this server.

Often times, I use a browser called 'Torch', which is a chromium build.

In 'Torch', I have the ability to download a single file on multiple threads - for instance, a thread runs for the first 8th of the file, another for the second, and so on, until I have 8 threads downloading from different positions in the file.

What I'm just realizing, is that however I have IIS configured, I am not able to download a file on multiple threads like this. That is - when I start a download from Our server ( as opposed to this working on many other servers ), I only get one download thread.

Anyone have any idea what configuration item might affect this?

Comment: Is this transfer being done with HTTP or FTP?

Comment: It's being transferred over HTTP - and I have seen the function work over HTTP previously.

Comment: You've seen it work with *your* IIS previously?

Comment: Negative. I've seen it work on other servers - running who-knows-what.

Comment: Gotcha.  Perhaps more info abut you IIS setup is in order.  Is it a single server, or a farm?  Are you pulling from a standard web site, or is it a .Net Web App or something?

Comment: PHP build, normal website in most respects. No URL rewrites or anything fancy. Little mime configuration. Single server.